# Embed HTML into a DLL

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, vs-web-application-project

This question stems from a recent topic I made about setting up [Web Application Project references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406321/web-application-structure-and-deployment) but I think is unique enough to merit its own post.

We have a web application that has some aspx pages with code-behind as well as html pages and other files (js, images, etc).  When the project is built, all of the application code (cs files) gets compiled into a DLL.  Is it possible to compile the html, js, and other files into the DLL as well?  We want to set up a project reference that would be able to use the non-compiled source included in this parent project.  Would this even work with IIS?

Comment: I'll go back and take a look, but to be honest, I haven't really gotten  too much useful input... my questions might be overly specific or something.  I think this ones kind of generic... maybe.

Comment: @yourbuddypal: If you have found the answer on your own it's more acceptable to post it and accept it then to not accept anything.

Answer (score 1):

My preference is to load the html into resource files and access it by key name for output generation. I have used it for small things such as templated controls and big things such as providing entire page layout for dynamically generated content. There are plenty of resources describing the usage of resource files to provide this kind of content. The advantage I find is that an entire dll can be packaged up and used solely to provide these resources to a multitude of separate applications as long as there is a consistency to how the content is delivered/produced.